# Why does my list of items sort incorrectly after many multiple updates?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, meteor

I'm using Meteor, and I have a list of items like:

Todo A

Todo B

Todo C

Todo D

But then after calling multiple updates one after another:

```
Todos.find().forEach(function(todo) {
    Todos.update(todo._id, {$set: {  
                strength:s,
                retention:r,    
                }}, 
        function(err, res){
            if(err){throw err}
            console.log('updated '+res+' doc');
    })  
})
```

Todo A

Todo D

Todo C

Todo B

the list order becomes messed up.  If I refresh it's fine again and sorted accordingly.  Why could this be?

```
Template.listsShow.helpers({
    editing: function() {
        return Session.get(EDITING_KEY);
    },

    todosReady: function() {
        return Router.current().todosHandle.ready();
    },

    todos: function(listId) {
        var obj =  Todos.find({listId: listId}, {sort: {createdAt : 1}});
        return obj;
    }
});

//Server Side 
Meteor.publish('todos', function(listId) {
    check(listId, String);
    return Todos.find({listId: listId});
});





{
    "_id" : "6pELT5pmGoXQhh2eG",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-01-02T23:58:12.236Z")
}
{
    "_id" : "4ES3hbJX76nLCJGGL",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-01-02T23:58:12.236Z")
}
{
    "_id" : "NzModCoCHcbWdWo22",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-01-02T23:58:12.236Z")
}
{
    "_id" : "tzgK3EdMrBi8SbGBn",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-01-02T23:58:12.236Z")
```

Comment: Please include the helper you are using to render the todo documents. Are you applying a sort in that helper?

Comment: @DavidWeldon Yes I believe so, I added it above

Comment: This seems very close to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813567/meteor-not-sorting-on-client-immediately-after-publication , but I'm not sure how to implement Tracker.autorun within the helper

Comment: How is `createdAt` being written? Could it be that you accidentally added an update hook that modifies `createdAt`?

Comment: `createdAt` is only written once when the todo is created, but if multiple todos are created at once which does happen perhaps they have the same date, I'll look into that possibility thank you.

Comment: yup that does look possible.  Look above.

Comment: Yep, so because the create dates are all the same, they will just be sorted arbitratily. Maybe try `{sort: {createdAt: 1, message: 1}}` or something.

Comment: i did this `var createdAt = new Date(new Date().getTime() + l); ` where l is an incrementing integer and it works great

Comment: Thanks so much.  post something and I'll green check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on our conversation above, it looks like the issue had to do with the fact that several of the documents had the same value for `createdAt`. Therefore sorting on that field alone would result in an arbitrary ordering. If the documents were generated from a script, you could try randomizing the date. Additionally, you could sort on more than one field, for example: `{sort: {createdAt: 1, message: 1}}`.